# vcc and ground connection in schematic and pcb

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics

[image: pcb]
[image: pcb]

so I made my first pcb design using easyeda.com and the schematic and pcb [link](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=%7C0cd0c5096f2a42fca3924a333c491a0b%7C7ee197b1ec1a4699a37d9435024d010b%7C26a9f67b8785416bb8dcd7f8157b5db6)
My ground pins are all connected and i gave VCC too in the schematic but it is not shown in the PCB deign is that normal?
How can I improve my schematic and hence the PCB design(i have used autorouting for routing in PCB)
  **The PCB I designed is an Arduino mega shield and its mainly used to drive 6 stepper motor and 6 servo motor along with endtops each stepper motor is 12v 1.2A bipolar stepper motor and servo motor is 6v([towerpro](https://engineering.tamu.edu/media/4247823/ds-servo-mg90s.pdf)) mostly to move along different axis and servos for gripper(hold objects)**
ICs and parts I have used
[a4988 stepper motor driver](https://www.pololu.com/product/1182)
[l293d dual h bridge driver for servo](https://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/H-bridge_motor_driver.PDF)
[arduino mega 2560](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/a000047.pdf)
power jack to input power
some connector pins 4p & 3p connectors
updated schematics :
[image: sheet-1]
[image: sheet-2]
[image: sheet-3]

Comment: The link goes to easyeda, but (at least on my phone) it doesn't show any existing design.  Make screenshots and post those.

Comment: @JRE Link works properly on the computer (just a side note, you probably won't care lol)

Comment: @KingDuken:  I thought it might work on PCs, that's why I mentioned my phone.  In any case, pictures are better because this question will probably be around longer than the project on easyeda.

Comment: @JRE i will post screenshots

Comment: @KingDuken thanks. Because its my first time doing designing I am doubtful. My main doubt is if i have connected VCC and ground properly. Any suggestions to improve the PCB or Schematic?

Comment: Some of the traces look to be very close together (between the lower two rows of pins with the red traces is really close - in the picture, the two traces are smeared together.) Does easyeda have a design rules check?  That would tell you if they are too close.

Comment: All of the traces appear to be very thin.  This is a motor driver, right?  Will the traces carry the needed current?

Comment: In the schematic, some of the A4988 ICs have the Vcc and ground crossing, so that ground ends up above Vcc.  Drives me nuts.

Comment: You don't have any bypass caps or bulk capacitors on the motor drivers.  This design will not work well and probably will not work at all without them.  Take a look at the datasheets for the various components you are using and look for the bypass capacitor requirements.

Comment: @JRE 1. yes easyEda have DRC checking and it didnt show me any errors  2.i will increase the traces width(the motors will draw max of 1.2Amps)  3.VCC and gnd are not connected , but yes i will change that too

Comment: @DeanFranks i have referred http://reprap.org/wiki/Arduino_Mega_Pololu_Shield  i have added capacitor for the input 12V supply will that be enough ?

Comment: Fix the mess first, then I might look at it.  Those sideways ICs are really obnoxious, especially since you are asking others to look at your schematic as a favor.  Thumbing your nose at the volunteers here is not how to get free help.  Also, there are a lot of air wires, and it's not clear what each IC (or connector) is supposed to to.  It's difficult to see what is connected to what.

Comment: @OlinLathrop sideways ICs you meant a4988 ICs right? In PCB  layout i have placed it as similar to RAMPS 1.4 design http://reprap.org/wiki/Arduino_Mega_Pololu_Shield  and In schematic i will make the modification..thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Ramps board have a significant bulk capacitor on each motor driver.  You also need to set the width of the power supply traces to the motor drivers (VMot) to handle the 2A the drivers can operate at.  You can see a working example here: http://domoticx.com/arduino-mega-shield-ramps/ with schematics and a board layout.  Be aware, this board is not particularly well designed, the power supply traces to the motor driver should be wider and not daisy chained across multiple drivers.  Why are you not just using a RAMPs board? They are cheap as dirt.

Comment: In the design you linked, there is a 100uF cap on each motor driver, close to the driver and with wide traces, C3, C4, C7, C9, C10.

Comment: @DeanFranks I thought just one common capacitor was enough.I will add the capacitors .I am not using the RAMPS 1.4 board cause i need extra servos too added to it along with some changes(more components will be added later).What should be the width of the supply traces according to you?(I am completely new so pardon me for my ignorance)

Comment: I can't tell from your schematics what you are trying to accomplish, please redraw the schematics with part numbers/etc and we'll take another look.  A statement of what you are trying to accomplish will also help.